# Return list of Users attending where attendance is held in one table and name is in another

Tags: mysql

I'm putting together a website for my film club to manage RSVP's under covid.

I have the following query:

```
SELECT
    e.id, 
    e.title, 
    e.tagline, 
    e.poster_img, 
    e.youtube_link, 
    e.synpois, 
    e.description, 
    e.date AS 'when',
    e.imdb,
    e.cap,
    COUNT(r.user_id) AS users, 
    l.name,
    l.address,
    l.website 
FROM event e 
LEFT JOIN rsvp r ON e.id = r.event_id 
JOIN location l ON l.id = e.venue
WHERE e.date >= CURDATE() 
GROUP BY e.id
ORDER BY e.date ASC
```

This selects the all the events from the "`event`" table (`e`) where the event data is newer or equal to now.

I join to the "`rsvp`" table and get a count of users who have rsvp'd they're going to the event.

I also join a "`location`" table that pulls in the location details of where the film is being screened.

This all works great, I use a while loop in PHP and create my event listing page with all these details. The returned data looks like:

```
47 | The VelociPastor (2018) | Man of the clawth. | https://shitmovie.group/wp-content/uploads/2021/05... | 7Nyb0GqAjKM | After losing his parents, a priest travels to Chin... | Please RSVP so we can track attendees... | 2021-10-23 14:30:00 | https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1843303/ | 20 | 16 | The Hive Bar | 93 Erskineville Rd, Erskineville NSW 2043 | https://thehivebar.com.au/
55 | Tammy and the T-Rex (1994) | He's The Coolest Pet In Town! | https://shitmovie.group/wp-content/uploads/2021/05... | s2TjMvBmKuo | An evil scientist implants the brain of Michael, a... | Please RSVP so we can track attendees... | 2021-10-26 18:30:00 | https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0111361/ | 20 | 14 | The Hive Bar | 93 Erskineville Rd, Erskineville NSW 2043 | https://thehivebar.com.au/
54 | Cretaceous Park | https://shitmovie.group/wp-content/uploads/2018/08... | Fifth attempt at getting this going, we'll be goin... | 2021-10-30 18:00:00 | 99 | 16 | Federal Park Picnic Shelter | 2-2A Chapman Rd, Annandale NSW 2038 | https://www.cityofsydney.nsw.gov.au/parks/federal-...
49 | Poultrygeist: Night of the Chicken Dead (2006) | Humans... the other white meat... | https://shitmovie.group/wp-content/uploads/2021/05... | uWGKWkpC6ng | Zombified chickens attempt to kill the fast-food w...  | Please RSVP so we can track attendees and if you'r... | 2021-11-27 14:30:00 | https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0462485/ | 20 | 13 | The Hive Bar | 93 Erskineville Rd, Erskineville NSW 2043 | https://thehivebar.com.au/
```

However, I'd also like to show a list of names for those who have RSVP'd, not just the count I have currently - is this possible in the one query (and therefore simple to feed in to my while loop for the html generation)?

The table layout for RSVP is just:

```
id
user_id
event_id
waitlist
```

"`id`" just being an autoincrement int for each entry, "`user_id`" being the ID of the user and "`event_id`" being the ID of the event. ("`waitlist`" you can ignore, a boolean for if they rsvp'd after the cap was hit). The layout for the "`event`" & "`location`" tables are pretty much everything in the query and hopefully self explanatory from the column names.

I would need to join to a table called "`member`" to return the corresponding "`name`", such as:

```
JOIN member m ON m.id = r.user_id
```

I'm just not sure how to return all the "`r.user_id`" as a list in the original query, simply adding "`r.user_id`" to my select query returns the first value found, which I think my "`GROUP BY e.id`" is causing.

I've tried searching for a solution, but unclear how to actually describe my issue short enough for google to return something useful, most responses are just how to join tables which I'm comfortable with (as above) but not the more complex way I'm making this SQL query to make the PHP side of things easier.

Originally I had a site with all events click through to another page, so this was easy to return then for just the one event, but now I've been working on my CSS and AJAX and have pulled everything through to the one page, which I think works better (less clicking for users, all in the one place and hopefully by the time I'm finished more mobile friendly).

If it helps for context here's the original site: [events.shitmovie.group](https://events.shitmovie.group/overview.php) and here's the new site I'm working on the above code to get functional [poopointoh.shitmovie.group](https://poopointoh.shitmovie.group).

Answer (score 1):

That query seems to involve the "explode-implode" scenario.  First it gathers a big temp table from all the `JOINing`, then collapses it via the `GROUP BY`.  That can probably be sped up via:

Remove these two lines

```
LEFT JOIN rsvp r ON e.id = r.event_id 
GROUP BY e.id
```

and replace

```
    COUNT(r.user_id) AS users,
```

by

```
    ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM rsvp WHERE e.id = event_id ) AS users,
```

Consider using `GROUP_CONCAT()` for combining the user names into a single string.

Comment: Thanks, I updated the code for the "explode-implode"  but it gave an error:
`#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'ON e.id = r.event_id) AS users,
    l.name,
    l.address,
    l.website...' at line 15`
I'll look in to the `GROUP_CONCAT()` though, thanks for the pointers.

Comment: @Sam - My bad -- In that context, it needs `WHERE` instead of `ON`.